# Source Transformation Finding TEC

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, thevenin, source

[image]

I have been trying to find the thevenin equivalent circuit with respect to nodes a and b using source transformation. I end up having this setup. What would possibly be the next step I should do? Can I consider resistors(1 and 2) connected in parallel?

Comment: You can do more source transformations. No, resistors 1 and 2 are not parallel.

Comment: May I ask which source I should apply source transformation? Thank you @ElliotAlderson

Comment: What do you understand about source transformation? When can you transform a voltage source to a current source, and vice versa?

Comment: I realized that I should have just applied a wye to delta conversion to the resistors. Thank you for the help Sir.